# how to share gif images using intent sharing to available apps?

Tags: android, android-intent, gif, sharing

i want working on sharing .gif with available apps like whatsapp, but unable to get valid Uri of gif present in my drawable resource.

```
 Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://my_package_name/" + R.drawable.gif_1);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/gif");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
```

there is lot of solution on sharing images but no solution on gif sharing, Please help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found my answer, I just created a file with a .gif extension and it worked for me. See the code below:

```
private void shareGif(String resourceName){

    String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String fileName = "sharingGif.gif";

    File sharingGifFile = new File(baseDir, fileName);

    try {
        byte[] readData = new byte[1024*500];
        InputStream fis = getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable", getPackageName()));

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(sharingGifFile);
        int i = fis.read(readData);

        while (i != -1) {
            fos.write(readData, 0, i);
            i = fis.read(readData);
        }

        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException io) {
    }
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/gif");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(sharingGifFile);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Emoji"));
}
```

Comment: What if gif is on server?

Comment: @ButaniVijay : download gif locally and then share with same code :)

Comment: and if my gif file is in drawable folder than what should i pass in resourcename?

Comment: @ButaniVijay : I used your code but failed. my images are on server, I download it in storage, and then get the exact path, but still my app crashes and no error message in the logcat to remove the bug.

Comment: This code is not working. Only still image shared not the animated gif.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you want to take image from internal storage.

//this is method having internal storage path.
 private String getFilePath2() {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/Gifs temp/");
    if (!myDir.exists())
        myDir.mkdirs();
    String fname = "temp_gif";
    SimpleDateFormat timeStampFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
    Date myDate = new Date();
    String filename = timeStampFormat.format(myDate);
    File file = new File(myDir, fname + "_" + filename + ".gif");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    String str = file.getAbsolutePath();
    return str;
}




 //   Then take image from internal storage into the string.
  String st = getFilePath2();




 //And share this by this intent
 Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            shareIntent.setType("image/gif");
                            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(sharingGifFile);
                            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,        
  uri);

  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Emoji"));
```